# Data become erase during updation in android database

Tags: android

When I update the record the first data erased.I want to keep the old data and also the new data.
How is it possible to keep both the data without creating the other table for data.I heard about concat function but I don't know how to use.
This is my database:

```
       public boolean updateData_Second(String roll,String name)
           { SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
             ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
             cv.put(COL_SECOND_1,roll);
             cv.put(COL_SECOND_2,name);
          db.update(TABLE_SECOND_NAME,cv, "ROLL= ?",new String[]{roll});
        return true;
          }
```

And this is my java:

```
        boolean isUpdated = myDb.updateData(techno.getText().toString(),
           name.getText().toString());


                    if (isUpdated == true)
                   {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "updated",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "not updated", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

I am very confuse.I want to keep the old data with the new one.For example the olde data is "a" and the new onw is "b" so I want to have the both data "a" and "b" in the textview.

Comment: any body please

Comment: Use insert instead of update?